# Switching between forms and sending variable correctly

Tags: c#, forms

I am wondering how can I correctly switch between forms by button click event.

I have Form1 and Form2.
Form1 have: -TextBoxForm1
            -ButtonForm1
Form2 have: -TextBoxForm2
            -ButtonForm2

I would like to on_click ButtonForm1 event go to the Form2. Then I want to write some message to TextBoxForm2 and press ButtonForm2 it will go to the Form1 again and message from TextBoxForm2 will appear in TextBoxForm1.

Everything works fine, but I have one problem. When I close application and I wanna debug and start it again, some errors appear like:"application is already running".

Form1:

```
public static string MSG;
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TextBoxForm1.Text = MSG;
    }
private void ButtonForm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        this.Hide();
//There is probably my fault but when I was trying this.Close(); everything shutted down
        form2.Show();
    }
```

Form2:

```
private void ButtonForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1.MSG = TextBoxForm2.Text;
        Form1 form= new Form1();
        form.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
```

How can I do this correctly please? :) I am beginner, thank you!

Comment: Write an event handler for form2's FormClosing event.  Which tells you that you need to make your main window visible again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not go the route of using a STATIC for passing between forms as you mention you are a beginner, but lets get the closing to work for you.

In your main form create a new method to handle an event call as Hans mentioned in the comment.  Then, once you create your second form, attach to its closing event to force form 1 to just become visible again.

// Inside your Form1's class..

```
void ReShowThisForm( object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
   // since this will be done AFTER the 2nd form's click event, we can pull it
   // into your form1's still active textbox control without recreating the form
   TextBoxForm1.Text = MSG;
   this.Show();
}
```

and where you are creating form2

```
private void ButtonForm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Form2 form2 = new Form2();
   form2.Closing += ReShowThisForm;
   this.Hide();
   form2.Show();
}
```

and in your second form click, you should only need to set the static field and close the form

```
private void ButtonForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Form1.MSG = TextBoxForm2.Text;
   this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution is to use modal form. Display `Form2` *temporarily*, when it is displayed `Form1` is invisible.

```
var form2 = new Form2();
this.Visible = false; // or Hide();
form2.ShowDialog(this);
this.Visible = true;
```

And to pass data you can define property in `Form2`, to example:

```
public string SomeData {get; set;}
```

`Form1` has to set `SomeData`, which you take in `Shown` and display. Same property can be used to get data from `Form2` (before closing).

```
// form 1 click
var form2 = new Form2() { SomeData = TextBoxForm1.Text; }
this.Visible = false;
form2.ShowDialog(this);
this.Visible = true;
TextBoxForm1.Text = form2.SomeData;

// form 2 shown
TextBoxForm2.Text = SomeData;

// form 2 click
SomeData = TextBoxForm2.Text;
Close();
```

Comment: yes, a showDialog is a good option, but we don't know the rest of the intent the form is/will be doing.  Also, what if multiple settings are desired from the second form to be returned to the first.  There are many ways to work a solution, but I was just going based on what they already started.  Always good to learn how / where hooking into event handlers can be used.

Comment: @DRapp, I have bad habit to see *XY problem* in every question, so here is *alternative* solution ;)